# Next.js: Calling Thunks in getServerSideProps with next-redux-wrapper with TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, next.js, redux-thunk

I'm trying to dispatch a `thunk` from the `getServerSideProps` in Next.js using `next-redux-wrapper` store. However, I keep getting the following typescript error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '(dispatch: any) => Promise<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.   Property 'type' is missing in type '(dispatch: any) => Promise<any>' but required in type 'AnyAction'.
```

I haven't used TypeScript with Redux before, so not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

My code is as follows:

```
// page.tsx

export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(
  async ({ store, params }) => {
    store.dispatch(myThunkFunction(params.id));

    return {
      props: {
        id: params.id,
      },
    };
  });
```

```
// thunks.ts

export const myThunkFunction = id => {
  return async dispatch => {
    ...
  };
};
```

Answer (score 5):

[It seems to be a known issue with `next-redux-wrapper` when using `redux-thunk`](https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper/issues/207), where the `dispatch` type returned by `next-redux-wrapper` in `getServerSideProps` (or `getInitialProps` as that is what I'm using) isn't a `ThunkDispatch`.

I spent a lot of time trying to figure out what the issue was and managed to find a work around by creating an application thunk dispatch type like

`export type AppThunkDispatch = ThunkDispatch<ApplicationState, void, AnyAction>`

And when using it inside `getServerSideProps` (or `getInitialProps`) you would just cast the `store.dispatch` to it.

`const thunkDispatch = store.dispatch as AppThunkDispatch`

I haven't tried it with `getServerSideProps` but I'm assuming the store passed to it will be the same as the store passed to `getInitialProps`...